# Off topic close dialog options

Tags: feature-request, migration

Following the [New Question Migration Paths](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths/) blog post, you (mods and those with close right) should ask for links to the sites you'd like questions to be migrated to.

[image]
[<sup>Click to embiggen picture.</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9wqJ.png)

You will need to add links to existing questions that should be/have been migrated to the site in question - see [Jeff's answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/option-to-migrate-to-super-user/719#719) to my equivalent question on Web Apps meta.

Comment: @badp - thanks for the screen shot

Comment: Is this going to happen any time soon? I wanted to migrate [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23424/where-can-i-go-to-find-a-game-graphic-artist) to game dev...

Comment: @fredley - I don't know. I've raised the issue with the team and I'll bump the question so it hits the first page of meta too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to warn some of you: Super User isn't aimed at troubleshooting game-related problems.

So in most cases questions that are being asked here (being specifically aimed at games) won't be allowed in that same form on Super User. I'd prefer if the user took the effort to generalize his question to be applicable to his computer in general, then having his gaming specific question migrated.

And as a general guideline for migrating: **when in doubt, don't migrate!**

This applies to most sites, where you aren't a (real) user yourself, the reason the question is asked on your sub-site is often enough indication that it isn't allowed on another (beginner mistakes aside).

So instead of migrating your own 'crap' away, either close them or if they are simply poor, don't migrate but delete them.

Comment: Hey @Ivo. Could you validate [these](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3185/good-cheap-external-data-source-for-storing-and-playing-games-closed) [two](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4522/does-the-sapphire-radeon-hd-5670-require-an-extra-power-connector-closed) Super User migration candidates and let me know if they're okay to move? Thanks in advance! ♪

Comment: @Grace, one was reasked and answered! on Super User (http://superuser.com/questions/166310/external-data-source-for-read-intensive-applications), I would consider deleting two as it's not a real question.

Answer (score 11):

In whatever order the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ uses:
<sub>(key: **must have**, nice to have, <s>pointless</s>)</sub>

- <s>Photography</s>
- Android Enthusiasts (what's a good port of nethack for android?)
- <s>TeX - LaTeX</s>
- <s>Programmers</s>
- <s>Home Improvement</s>
- <s>Electronics and Robotics</s>
- <s>Cooking</s>
- Unix and Linux (does WoW run well on WINE?)
- <s>Personal Finance and Money</s>
- <s>User Interface</s>
- Web Applications (how can I change my display name in FarmVille?)

  - [Case 1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10431/are-bookmarklet-safe-with-facebook-data)
- <s>Meta Stack Overflow</s>
- <s>Stack Overflow</s>
- <s>Mathematics</s>
- <s>GIS</s>
- **Role-playing Games**

  - [Case One](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10253/when-rolling-a-check-for-something-obscure-what-are-you-checking-against)
- <s>Stack Apps</s>
- **Super User**

  - [Case One](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3185/good-cheap-external-data-source-for-storing-and-playing-games-closed)
  - [Case Two](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4522/does-the-sapphire-radeon-hd-5670-require-an-extra-power-connector-closed)
- Server Fault (my minecraft server can't ping other machines)
- <s>English Language and Usage</s>
- <s>Webmasters</s>
- <s>Theoretical Computer Science</s>
- Apple (roguelikes for the iOS?)
- **Game Developers**

  - [Case One](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3358/best-way-to-test-simple-cases-in-games)
  - [Case Two](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2045/approachable-and-fun-pc-game-development-environments-for-kids)
  - [Case Three](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/how-do-i-externally-manage-a-directx-games-speed) (assuming the user was actually testing a flash game and not simply cheating)
  - [Case Four](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8058/wow-lua-getting-quest-attributes-before-the-quest-detail-event) (this one has already been moved)
  - [Case Five](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18715/best-game-engine-2d-for-ios)
- <s>Bicycles</s>
- Ubuntu (how do I install minecraft in Ubuntu?)
- <s>OnStartups</s>
- <s>WordPress</s>
- <s>Statistical Analysis</s>
- **Board and Card games**

So I guess that makes RPG, SU, GDev, SF for now.

Comment: [Related](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games), [related](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11942/game-of-go), ...

Comment: Just as a note - I think only graduated sites will appear in the dialog, so this won't be fully implemented until all mentioned sites have been through the whole process.

Comment: How do I play sc2 while riding a bicycle, chatting in proper English while managing to keep my job as a webmaster mathematician (or should I begin working on my start up?)? Should I post this to my wordpress blog?

Comment: @Juan How do I programmatically move the paddle in pong while microwaving my leased iPod connected via VPN to an Ubuntu client with horrible UI that is taking geotagged photos of brownian-motion-moving flashes in O(n log² n) without harming my unicorn-branded Android-powered robot bicycle unit?

Comment: Exactly... where would I ask that?

Comment: @Juan Home Improvement

Comment: Fully agree with superuser, gamedev and any gaming-SEs-which-aren't-about-video-games; but I have a feeling serverfault will very rare.

Comment: gameserver management, the non-gaming part (firewalls, etc.).

Comment: I don't think any of the examples posted in your related question in meta.serverfault support a migration path to SF. Without wishing to sound rude, SF is for professional sysadmins, and I suspect most people won't see gaming server as "professional" (not hating on gamers, I'm a proud PC and xbox360 gamer myself).

Comment: @Robert No worries. I asked on meta.SF exactly to get your opinion.

Comment: Jin is starting on RPG's design, so it should be launching in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @Juan - "hf" or "gg"  is not proper English so that narrows it down a bit.