# Add "Game Development" to off-topic selection list when flagging a post

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, migration

I've noticed a few different questions recently that were better asked on the [Game Development Stack Exchange site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). Considering how closely the two sites are related, I would assume that such occurrences would only increase as site traffic increased. I think it'd be a good idea to add the Game Development SE site to our list of "off topic destination candidates". Currently, the only site there is Meta @ Gaming (see below).

In addition, I've seen one or two questions that were good candidates for [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). The frequency is so intermittent that I don't think we need them on this list at the moment, but if we're looking to fill out the list, those would be reasonable candidates.

Regardless of that, I firmly believe the Game Development SE would be a good fit for this list.

[image: off-topic list]

Comment: @badp can you provide a source or explanation of how you know this is deferred?

Comment: @Oak I thought I did but my connectivity is being lousy today. Rebecca looked into this and said that 7 migrated questions aren't enough evidence to offer gamedev as a migration options to users. As always, you can ask diamond mods to consider migration via the flag → flag for moderator attention option.

Comment: @badp For future reference, what kind of percentage to they look for before providing the migration option?

Comment: There's no set number, percentage or threshold. There just needs to be a history of successfully migrated questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Off topic close dialog options](http://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/off-topic-close-dialog-options)

Answer (score 6):

I like the ease at which I can [draw this question out](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/off-topic-close-dialog-options). We've got summat of an outstanding ticket for it already, actually. You can help support it by putting more links in that Meta post.

Migration paths will only be opened if enough evidence for the need is supplied. Hard evidence is really appreciated, so gather up links that you find! ♪

For the curious, here is a list of all questions we've migrated to Game Development that have *not* been closed afterwards. Some are deleted here, though. There are 7 in total right now, which isn't all that much weight. So if you can find more, we can push for this easier.

- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/looking-for-an-open-source-tile-based-turn-based-wargame-engine
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15910/wow-lua-getting-quest-attributes-before-the-quest-detail-event
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14597/starcraft-2-third-person-custom-map
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14278/how-to-move-the-object-around-the-screen
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14096/how-should-i-show-shared-resources-during-a-shared-resource-game-in-the-galaxy-ed
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13689/collision-detection-for-2d
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13417/civilization-4-time-in-own-scenario-runs-up-too-quickly

I'll also note the following, which was not actually migrated but got manually reposted. There are probably a couple more instances.

- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3358/best-way-to-test-simple-cases-in-games

Comment: Hrrmm. I tried searching and I reviewed the list of questions that popped up when I entered my subject, but apparently I'm not on the ball this morning. :(

Comment: Only [one more](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/how-do-i-externally-manage-a-directx-games-speed) comes to mind immediately, and it's kind of a fuzzy middle-ground. It's worded in such a way that the user is developing/testing a flash game, but he could easily be trying to cheat at flash games. Either way, it's something Game Development would be better-equipped to answer.

Comment: @Shaun We migrate questions because they don't belong in the current site, not because they can be better answered on the target site. I already know about that question, and I'm hoping for the author to explain the scenario first before we decide on where the question should go.

Comment: Agreed, which is why I mention it's a fuzzy middle-ground. It only *belongs* on Game Development if he's actually testing a game he's developing.

Comment: Here's [another one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16403/design-logic-where-to-start). Since it hasn't been moved yet, I won't edit it into your answer.